# numpy - selecting elements from an array with spacing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with a bunch of monotonically increasing values.  Say,

```
a = [1,2,3,4,6,10,10,11,14]
a_arr=np.array(a)
```

Also say

```
thresh = 4
```

I want to create an array that contains the indices of a subset of `a_arr` which steps through the array, selecting elements but ignoring elements that aren't spaced at least `thresh` away from the last selection.  This might be more easily described with an algorithm:

```
def select_idx(a, thresh):
    ret = []
    for idx, elt in enumerate(a):
        if len(ret) == 0 or elt >= a[ret[-1]] + thresh:
            ret.append(idx)
    return ret
```

Obviously I could do this using exactly this function, but that seems slow.  Any way to vectorize this in numpy?

Thanks.

P.S. In this example, select_idx(a, thresh) = [0, 4, 5, 8]

**Edit**: An approximate version of this problem might be easier to vectorize: divide the number line into buckets of size `thresh`, I guess starting from the first value in a.  So the bucket dividers in this example would be 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, ....   Select the indices of the numbers that are the first element in their bucket.  (Yes, I realize this isn't the same thing as what I wrote before.)

Comment: How could you vectorise it, when the decision at any particular position depends on all the previous values

Comment: I guess I hadn't thought about that, thanks for the comment.  My use case doesn't actually have to be very precise though, so I edited the question to include a probably easier problem.

Comment: Actually, I think you can just use `searchsorted` for this...

Comment: Yeah something like `a.searchsorted(np.arange(0, a[-1], thresh))`

Comment: Also `(a / 4.).astype(int)`  might give you some ideas ...

Comment: For the binning approach you could utilize a numpy's histogramm ``np.histogram()``.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized solution to your approximate problem:

```
idx = np.cumsum(np.bincount((a-a[0])/thresh))[:-1]
```

This gives you all the indices except for the first zero, which is always present. Here's the explanation:

1. `(a-a[0])/thresh` does integer division (assuming `a` has an integer dtype) to bin the values into groups `thresh` wide.
2. `cumsum(bincount(...))` counts the size of each group and converts them into indices. Note that if there's no values in a bucket `bincount` will report 0, so there may be repeats in this array.
3. Finally, we discard the last index, which corresponds to the size of `a`. Alternatively, if the order of indices doesn't matter, you could exploit this to get your zero index back:

   ```
   idx = np.cumsum(np.bincount((a-a[0])/thresh)) % len(a)
   ```