# Best way to pick random elements from an array with at least a min diff in R

Tags: arrays, r, random

I would like to randomly choose from an array a certain number of elements in a way that those respect always a limit in their reciprocal distance. 
For example, having a vector `a <- seq(1,1000)`, how can I pick 20 elements with a minimum distance of 15 between each other?

For now, I am using a simple iteration for which I reject the choice whenever is too next to any element, but it is cumbersome and tends to be long if the number of elements to pick is high. Is there a best-practice/function for this?

**EDIT - Summary of answers and analysis**

So far I had two working answers which I wrapped in two specific functions.

```
# dash2 approach
# ---------------
rand_pick_min <- function(ar, min.dist, n.picks){
  stopifnot(is.numeric(min.dist), 
            is.numeric(n.picks), n.picks%%1 == 0)
  if(length(ar)/n.picks < min.dist) 
    stop('The number of picks exceeds the maximum number of divisions that the array allows which is: ', 
         floor(length(ar)/min.dist))
  picked <- array(NA, n.picks)
  copy <- ar
  for (i in 1:n.picks) {
    stopifnot(length(copy) > 0)  
    picked[i] <- sample(copy, 1)
    copy <- copy[ abs(copy - picked[i]) >= min.dist ]
  }
  return(picked)
}

# denis approach
# ---------------
rand_pick_min2 <- function(ar, min.dist, n.picks){
  require(Surrogate)
  stopifnot(is.numeric(min.dist), 
            is.numeric(n.picks), n.picks%%1 == 0)
  if(length(ar)/n.picks < min.dist) 
    stop('The number of picks exceeds the maximum number of divisions that the array allows which is: ', 
         floor(length(ar)/min.dist))
  lar <- length(ar)
  dist <- Surrogate::RandVec(a=min.dist, b=(lar-(n.picks)*min.dist), 
                             s=lar, n=(n.picks+1), m=1, Seed=sample(1:lar, size = 1))$RandVecOutput
  return(cumsum(round(dist))[1:n.picks])
}
```

Using the same example proposed I run 3 tests. Firstly, the effective validity of the minimum limit

```
# Libs
require(ggplot2)
require(microbenchmark)

# Inputs
a <- seq(1, 1000)            # test vector
md <- 15                     # min distance
np <- 20                     # number of picks

# Run
dist_vec <- c(sapply(1:500, function(x) c(dist(rand_pick_min(a, md, np)))))   # sol 1
dist_vec2 <- c(sapply(1:500, function(x) c(dist(rand_pick_min2(a, md, np))))) # sol 2

# Tests - break the min
cat('Any distance breaking the min in sol 1?', any(dist_vec < md), '\n')  # FALSE
cat('Any distance breaking the min in sol 2?', any(dist_vec2 < md), '\n') # FALSE
```

Secondly, I tested for the distribution of the resulting distances, obtaining the first two plots in order of solution (sol1 [A] is dash2's sol, while sol2 [B] is denis' one).

```
pa <- ggplot() + theme_classic() +
  geom_density(aes_string(x = dist_vec), fill = 'lightgreen') +
  geom_vline(aes_string(xintercept = mean(dist_vec)), col = 'darkred') + xlab('Distances')
pb <- ggplot() + theme_classic() +
  geom_density(aes_string(x = dist_vec2), fill = 'lightgreen') +
  geom_vline(aes_string(xintercept = mean(dist_vec)), col = 'darkred') + xlab('Distances')
print(pa)
print(pb)
```

[image: pdfs of distances]
Lastly, I computed the computational times needed for the two approaches as following and obtaining the last figure.

```
comp_times <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  'solution_1' = rand_pick_min(a, md, np),
  'solution_2' = rand_pick_min2(a, md, np),
  times = 500
)
ggplot2::autoplot(comp_times); ggsave('stckoverflow2.png')
```

[image: Computational times]

Enlighted by the results, I am asking my-self if the distance distribution as it is should be expected or it is a deviation due to the applied methods.

**EDIT2 - Answer to the last question, following the comment made by denis**

Using many more sampling procedures (5000), I produced a pdf of the resulting positions and indeed your approach contains some artefact that makes your solution (B) deviate from the one I needed. Nonetheless, it would be interesting to have the ability to enforce a specific final distribution of positions.
[image: distribution of positions]

Comment: This question is similar in python but it seems to me that it is lacking the randomization procedure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916979/numpy-selecting-elements-from-an-array-with-spacing

Comment: One solution, if you have a range like `a`, is to add a random number to your last choice: `picked[i] <- picked[i-1] + sample(15:100, 1)`. But this won't work for arbitrary vectors, and it might be hard to ensure it is uniformly random... but then given your requirements, you can't have uniformly random choices.

Comment: thanks for the testing !! It looks that dash2's answer is most of the time faster and gives smoother distribution (the histogramm of the position is really flat using dash2's answer compared to mine). I think the distance distribution is what it should be, peak should be at 1000/20 = 50. It is easier to check with the plot of the distribution of position (which should be flat).

Comment: I added also this analysis and it seems you are right ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution, which guarantees randomness in some sense (I'm not exactly sure what sense!) may be:

1. Pick a random element
2. Remove all elements that are too close to that element
3. Pick another element
4. Return to 2.

So:

```
min_dist <- 15
a <- seq(1, 1000)
picked <- integer(20)
copy <- a
for (i in 1:20) {
  stopifnot(length(copy) > 0)
  picked[i] <- sample(copy, 1)
  copy <- copy[ abs(copy - picked[i]) >= min_dist ]
}
```

Whether this is faster than sample-and-reject may depend on the characteristics of the original vector. Also, as you can see, you are not guaranteed to be able to get all the elements you want, though in your particular case there won't be a problem because 19 intervals of width 30 could never cover the whole of `seq(1, 1000)`.

Comment: As shown in my edit, your answer is the fastest and the most reliable. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One tiny change to make sure `stop` isn't called on the final run.

Comment: That is great! thanks, I updated also my answer review :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid the hit and miss methods, you will have to translate your problem into a sampling of distances with constraints on the sum of your distances.

Basically how i translate what you want: your N positions sampled are equivalent to N+1 distance, ranging from the minimum distance to the size of your vector - N*mindist (the case where all your samples are packed together). You then need to constrain the sum of the distances to be equal to 1000 (the size of your vector).

In this case the solution will use Surrogate::RandVec from Surrogate package (see [Random sampling to give an exact sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016047/random-sampling-to-give-an-exact-sum/49016585#49016585)), that allows a sampling with a fixed sum.

```
library(Surrogate)
a <- seq(1,1000)
mind <- 15
N <- 20
dist <- Surrogate::RandVec(a=mind, b=(1000-(N)*mind), s=1000, n=(N+1), m=1, Seed=sample(1:1000, size = 1))$RandVecOutput
pos <- cumsum(round(dist))[1:20]
pos

> pos
 [1]  22  59  76 128 204 239 289 340 389 440 489 546 567 607 724 773 808 843 883 927
```

`dist` is the sampling f the distance. You reconstruct your position by making the sum of the distances. It gives you `pos`, the vector of your index positions.

The advantage is that you can get any value, and that your sampling is supposed to be random. For the speed part I don't know, you'll need to compare to your method for your big data case.

Here is an histogramm of 1000 try:

[image]